# .NET Framework 4 requires Framework 2 or 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm a little confused. We have developed an net 4.0 application. We use nhibernate ( it has dependencies with .net 2 and 3.5). We have some machines with windows xp and framework 4 installed, framework 2, 3, and 3.5 were uninstalled. And the application runs ok. But, on production enviroment, it doesn't work. The message is like "the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling this application may fix this problem." We ran checkasm and saw that references to system.core version 3.5, system.ServiceModel version 3, and system.xml.linq version 3.5 are missing. Those references are done by nhibernate 3.1.
Seems like referenced dlls has dependency on framework 2, 3, and 3.5.
The question is: do i need to install those frameworks?
It's my understanding that, net 4 is an "standalone" framework, unlike net 3 and 3.5 that are "extensions" of net 2.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your patient

Comment: I'm confused by this: "We use nhibernate ( it has dependencies with .net 2 and 3.5)".  Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: .Net 4 allows side-by-side compatibility with 2,3 and 3.5. Thus it must be something else which is your problem. Details are explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx outlines to configure multiple runtimes if needed.

Comment: @RQDQ thanks, i'm confused too. I have probed the application with just net 4 and works (2, 3 and 3.5 were uninstalled).

Comment: @weismat, thanks i will read the article, thanks for the information

Comment: "We use nhibernate ( it has dependencies with .net 2 and 3.5)" then I think you must have these frameworks on production environment.

Comment: @weismat would you like post your comment as an answer? so i can accepted. I solved the problem creating a new project . It seems to be a problem in the project configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net 4 allows side-by-side compatibility with 2,3 and 3.5. 
Thus it must be something else which is your problem. Details are explained here: [Side by Side Compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx)

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx) outlines to configure multiple runtimes if needed.

Comment: Thanks. This article helps me to undertand a couple of things.